# why this is not compiling

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I'm having this problem:
StorageFactory.sol:13:27: ParserError: Expected ';' but got '('
simpleStorage store(_simpleStorageNumber);
^

---

and this is my code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
import "./SimpleStorage.sol"; 
contract StorageFactory{
    
    SimpleStorage[] public simpleStorageArray;
    function createSimpleStorageContract() public {
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
        simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage);
    }
     function sfStore(uint256 _simpleStorrageIndex, uint256 _simpleStorageNumber) public{
      SimpleStorage simpleStorage =  SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorageArray[_simpleStorageIndex])); 
       simpleStorage store(_simpleStorageNumber);   

     }
```

Comment: Insted of calling simpleStorage store(_simpleStorageNumber);  call - simpleStorage["index"] = (_simpleStorageNumber); // enter the index you need insted of "index"

Comment: provide simpleStorage Contract as well ?

Comment: @sms, I want to enter the contact

Comment: @NGDeveloper
 Thx, but it didn't I still have the same error with your help.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what exactly the SimpleStorage.sol contract you are importing is contain but if i understand it right then this might help -

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;

import "./SimpleStorage.sol"; 
contract StorageFactory{
    
    SimpleStorage[] public simpleStorageArray;

    function createSimpleStorageContract() public 
    {
        SimpleStorage simpleStorageContract = new SimpleStorage();
        simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorageContract);
    }

     function sfStore(uint256 _simpleStorrageIndex, uint256 _simpleStorageNumber) public
     {
       SimpleStorage simpleStorageContract =  SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorageArray[_simpleStorageIndex])); 
       simpleStorageContract.store(_simpleStorageNumber);   
     }
}
```

If this is not helping, please show us the code for the simpleStorage contract.

Anyway the solution you trying to create will be very costy.
Here is a cotract that get your goal without using another contract and is much cheaper to run -

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Answer
{
    mapping(address => uint) public StorageMap; //collection of address and numbers

    function InsertToStorage(address name, uint favoritenumber) public //insert a address and favorite number 
    {
        StorageMap[name] = favoritenumber;
    }

    function GetFavoriteNumber(address name) public view returns(uint) //insert an address and return the favorite number of that address 
    {
        return StorageMap[name];
    }
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: the simplestorage.sol I can store a name and a favorite number and I could enter a name and find his favorite number.

Comment: I will be happy to help, please press "edit" on your question and add the SimpleStorage.sol code.

Comment: I updated the answer with another way to achive your goal. Hope that will help.